# One liner if an index doesnt exists

Tags: python

For a lot of objects before calling `.append()` I do something like:

```
if not d.get('turns'):
    d['turns'] = []
```

Is there a oneliner in Python to do this?

After some answers, here's my kind of code:

```
d = json.loads(str(self.data))
if not d.get('turns'):
    d['turns'] = []
d['turns'].append({
    'date': time_turn,
    'data': data
})
```

Comment: If you can work with dicts instead, use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Comment: `d['turns'] = [] if not d.get('turns')` ?

Comment: I've updated my question to be more precise

Comment: Q:  why are you using `get()` rather than `in`?

Comment: Because I'm a beginner in Python

Comment: I'm not sure how your edit changes anything @OlivierPons. Don't the answers (particularly niemmi's) still apply?

Comment: Fair enough:  `if not 'turns' in d: d['turns'] = []`  The `in` keyword can be used  to check for the presence of keys - you can use it with strings and lists as well.  Really old versions of Python didn't have it (I think it came in at 2.4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a oneliner in Python to do this?

Yes

```
d.setdefault('turns', [])
```

Demo:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d.setdefault('turns', [])
[] # the inserted value is also returned
>>> d
{'turns': []}
```

If the key is found, `setdefault` behaves like `get`:

```
>>> d['turns'].append(1)
>>> d.setdefault('turns', 'irrelevant')
[1]
```

Comment: I've up-ed you because it answer exactly to my question, even though other answers are very interesting. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
d['turns'] # []
```

Other option is to use [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
d.setdefault('turns', []) # []
d.setdefault('turns', 'foo') # []
```

**UPDATE** Given the full code you could either write

```
d = defaultdict(list, json.loads(str(self.data)))
d['turns'].append({'date': time_turn, 'data': data})
```

or

```
d = json.loads(str(self.data))
d.setdefault('turns', []).append({'date': time_turn, 'data': data})
```

Answer (score 3):

depending on if the get is standard, it likely has the option to specify a default return if the item is not found, so

```
d.get('turns', [])
```

will give you the value if it exists, or [] if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can "oneline" it using :

```
d['turns'] = [] if not d.get('turns')
```

Comment: Why not directly `d['turns'] =d.get('turns', [])` ?

Comment: Great idea too, I don't know if one is better than the other though.

Comment: And Python dont need the "`else`" like `d['turns'] = [] if not d.get('turns') ` **else...** ??